# Symfony 2.5.8 - Twig form error rendering

Tags: forms, symfony, error-handling, twig

So i am using Symfony 2.5.8 in my project.
I have set up a form and some validation on the entity which is bindet to the form.
Everything works correctly!

Now i am trying to change the form error rendering of twig.

I render the form in the view like this

```
 {{ form(form, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

The errors are now rendered above the specific input field.
How can i change this to render the error messages above the whole form?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your form using twig functions.
For example, for a form attribute named 'age', you can do the following :

```
{{ form_label(form.age) }}
{{ form_errors(form.age) }}
{{ form_widget(form.age) }}
```

Here is the [symfony doc about form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: Damn, i am so dumn, i've already that this but didn't tried rendering each row by itself:

 {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
         <div class="form-content">
            {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
             {{ form_label(form.name) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
             {{ form_end(form) }}
         </div>
this worked for me :D